# Configure Excel VBA Help for Offline Use

Tags: vba, excel

I recently acquired a new Windows 10 computer running Office 365.  This was purchased to replace my "old" Windows 7 machine running Excel 2007.

I frequently work on the road and would like to configure VBA Help to work on offline *(local)* help files.  Currently, whenever I touch <kbd>F1</kbd> in the VBA window it tries to go online for the information.

Is there any solution for this ??

Comment: Think you might be outta luck.  https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10643091-bring-back-offline-help-in-office-2016

Comment: Well, how about reassigning the shortcut of F1 and opening something you wish?

Comment: Vityata I don't think it's that easy. It usually opens help relevent to whatever you have currently selected... So it's not just a generic shortcut.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40326